# How to fix "column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous" in Laravel 8 Yajra datatable

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have use Yajra datatables in my Laravel project, but there is a problem when sorting (also searching) datatables.

> column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous

I know that this error is because other tables has `'created_at'` column.

but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $partners = Partner::with(['term', 'user', 'invoices', 'bills', 'transactions']);
    $users = User::get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
    $terms = Term::get(['id', 'name']);
    $banks = Bank::get(['id', 'name']);
    return view('inc.partners', compact('partners', 'users', 'terms', 'banks'));
}

public function datatable()
{
    $partners = Partner::with(['term', 'user', 'invoices', 'bills', 'transactions'])->latest();

    return Datatables::of($partners)
        ->editColumn('full_name', function($partner) {
            return '<a href="'. route('partners.show', $partner->id) .'">' . $partner->full_name . '</a>';
        })->escapeColumns([])
        ->editColumn('term', function ($partner) {
            return $partner->term->name;
        })
        ->addColumn('type', function($partner) {
            if ($partner->type == 'Bilateral') {
                return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Bilateral</span>';
            } elseif ($partner->type == 'Customer') {
                return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Customer</span>';
            } else {
                return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Supplier</span>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('user', function ($partner) {
            return '<a href="'. route('users.show', $partner->user->id) .'">' . $partner->user->first_name . ' ' . $partner->user->last_name . '</a>';
        })
        ->addColumn('balance', function ($partner) {
            return ($partner->invoices->sum('actual_invoice_amount') - $partner->bills->sum('actual_bill_amount')) + ($partner->transactions->where('type', 'credit')->sum('final_amount') - $partner->transactions->where('type', 'debit')->sum('final_amount'));
        })
        ->editColumn('status', function ($partner) {
            if ($partner->status) {
                return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Active</span>';
            } else {
                return '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">InActive</span>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function ($partner) {
            return
        '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="edit-partner"
            onclick="edit_partner(this)"
            data-target="#edit_partner"
            data-id="'.$partner->id.'"
            data-action="'. route('partners.update', $partner->id) .'"
            data-full_name="'.$partner->full_name . '"
            data-code="'.$partner->code. '"
            data-street1="'.$partner->street1. '"
            data-country="'.$partner->country. '"
            data-state="'.$partner->state. '"
            data-city="'.$partner->city. '"
            data-zip_code="'.$partner->zip_code. '"
            data-type="'.$partner->type. '"
            data-inbound_credit="' . $partner->inbound_credit . '"
            data-outbound_credit="' . $partner->outbound_credit . '"
            data-notice_contacts="' . $partner->notice_contacts . '"
            data-status="' . $partner->status . '"
            data-credit="' . $partner->credit . '"
            data-debit="' . $partner->debit . '"
            data-user_id="' . $partner->user_id . '"
            data-term_id="' . $partner->term_id . '"
            ><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a>

            <a href="'. route('partners.destroy', $partner->id) .'" data-toggle="modal"
             onclick="delete_partner('.$partner->id.')"
             ><i class="icon-trash text-danger"></i></a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

My datatables scripts:

```
  $(function() {
        let partnersdatatable = $('#partnersdatatable-table').DataTable({
            pageLength: 100,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('partners.datatable') }}',
            columns: [{
                    data: 'code',
                    name: 'code'
                },
                {
                    data: 'full_name',
                    name: 'full_name'
                },
                {
                    data: 'term',
                    name: 'term.name'
                },
                {
                    data: 'inbound_credit',
                    name: 'inbound_credit'
                },
                {
                    data: 'outbound_credit',
                    name: 'outbound_credit'
                },
                {
                    data: 'user',
                    name: 'user.first_name'
                },
                {
                    data: 'type',
                    name: 'type'
                },
                {
                    data: 'balance',
                    name: 'balance'
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    name: 'status'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ],
            lengthMenu: [
                [10, 50, 100, 250, 3000, 5000],
                [10, 50, 100, 250, 3000, 5000]
            ],
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'colvis',
                text: '<i class="icon-three-bars"></i>',
                className: 'btn bg-blue btn-icon dropdown-toggle'
            }]
        });
        $('.filter-input').keyup(function() {
            partnersdatatable.column($(this).data('column')).search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the error picture:

[image]

This error exists almost in all my datatables.

How to fix the sorting and seaching error?

Answer (score 1):

On which line that caused the error. May be tracing back to another class?
Normally to fix the ambiguous column name, just add table name in front of column name such as users.created_at instead of just created_at.

Comment: Thanks @Saendee R. I posted the error picture in UPDATE 1 above. could you check it out?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your reply. I think the problem is with lastest() function. May be try it out with ->orderBy('table_name.created_at','desc')->first() or something like that instead of using lastest().